# Is it possible to change the lineup of elements without using remove() and append() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the values ​​returned as a result of the search query in a search bar in a certain order. And there are pictures in these values. For example, when a search is performed, a result like the following appears.

```
--1-- [img] Terst1
--2-- [img] Texast2
--3-- [img] Texast3
--4-- [img] kaTest3
--5-- [img] deTest3
```

Now let me tell you what I did in order. I start a search with **'te'** and get the following result.

```
--1-- [img] Terst1
--2-- [img] Texast2
--3-- [img] Texbst3
```

Then I continue this search as **'tex'**.

```
--2-- [img] Texast2
--3-- [img] Texbst3
```

No problems so far. However, when I search for **'texb'** and then delete the letter **'b'**, the following result appears.

```
--3-- [img] Texbst3
--2-- [img] Texast2
```

Here is where my problem starts. I want to sort the returned values ​​after deleting the letter **'b'**. But I don't want to re-append a data that is already shown. Because this way it reloads the already displayed image. For this, I used after() and before() by taking the ordinal value there and comparing it. However, this time I did not get what I wanted.

Is there a structure to move the 3rd element below the 2nd? Except for remove() and append().

As a result, what I want is to visit the elements here one by one and change their places. But by not using append() to reapply elements that have already been shown. I hope I could explain my problem.

EDIT:
One more example, when we inspect on page, we can move an element up and down with drag and drop in HTML. If I can make the jquery code for this it will be great.

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: Don't use `remove()` and `append()`. Use `hide()` and `show()`.

Comment: Or just `append` if not already exists

Comment: @Khalil 
There are many variables in the code, I don't think it can be understood that way.

Comment: @Barmar I can't use hide() and show() because there can be thousands of data. Which bloats the HTML.

Comment: Then the simplest way is to regenerate all of the filtered HTML as the user types, rather than trying to figure out where to insert and delete.

Comment: @Barmar Regenerate is not a problem, that way it can be resolved. But this time the images are reloaded again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I learnt that loaded images on the page already hold in cache. Since disable cache is turned on in the network tab in developer tools, it is constantly reloading the already existing image. When I turn off it, the problem went away.